# How to specify algorithm used to sort a list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Can we specify the sorting algorithm to use in python to sort a list. I want to compare multiple sorting algorithm and I don't want to write all by myself. Is there any in build module or any way in python that I can use it to sort the list.

like i want to use *buble_sort*, *insersion-sort*, *heap-sort* etc... I should be able to explictly specify the the algorithm to use.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting key functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, this is quite good.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/algorithms/0.1

This is fun, like for bubble sort,

```
from algorithms.sorting import bubble_sort
my_list = bubble_sort.sort(my_list)
```